# How to get information on a .woff font file from the command line?

Tags: linux, macos, fonts, info

I'm looking for something like ImageMagick `identify`.

I already know about `fc-scan` & `otfinfo` that work well for .otf fonts,
but I couldn't find anything for WOFF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [woffTools](https://github.com/typesupply/woffTools) :

> woffTools is a collection of command line tools for verifying and
>   examining WOFF files. This is also a Python package that can be used
>   to manipulate and examine WOFF files just as you can examine SFNT
>   files with FontTools.

```
woff-validate - Validate a WOFF file and output an HTML report.
woff-info - Generate an HTML file containing information about a WOFF file.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it now. So far, pip is having problems installing these, and I'm diagnosing.